# Problema con Page_Load para obtener valores de un textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Veran, tengo el siguiente problema.

En la siguiente imagen tengo una serie de datos que provienen de una base de datos, inicialmente esta deshabilitada la edición de los campos. Un botón llamado Modificar habilita los campos para editarlos.
[image: formulario para modificar información general]

En una pregunta que formulaba anteriormente tenia el problema que aunque el usuario editara el campo FEX.04 VIE, al actualizarlo (enviarlos datos a la base de datos), enviaba el dato que ven arriba. Ese problema lo solucione (en parte) usando la propiedad IsPostBack con un if(!IsPostBack). Digo solucionado en parte porque aunque ahora si envía a la base de datos el valor FEX.04 VIE editado, no soy capaz de hacer una comparación entre el dato anterior y el modificado porque me dice que son iguales, es decir, si pongo 8088, automáticamente el dato anterior y el modificado son iguales 8088.
Aquí dejo el código:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

public partial class zModificar_ModInfoGeneral : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
     Eliminacion elm = new Eliminacion();
     String nombre, valor, fechapropuesta, fechaVie;
     string regVieAnterior;
     bool confirm;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Request.QueryString["ID_Proy"] != null && Session["ID"] == null)
        {
            TablaContratos contratos = new TablaContratos();
            int idproy1 = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID_Proy"]);
            Session["ID"] = idproy1;
            Mostrar(idproy1);
            int id_contrato = contratos.Consultar_Id_Contrato(idproy1);

            if (id_contrato != 0)
            {
                Session["ID_Contrato"] = contratos.Consultar_Id_Contrato(idproy1);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["ID_Contrato"] = null;
            }
        }
        else if (Session["ID"] != null)
        {
            int id_proy2 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
            Mostrar(id_proy2);
        }

        estado.Text = "Aun no hay postback :D";
    }
    else
    {
        nombre = Txt_Nombre.Text;
        valor = Txt_Valor.Text;
        fechaVie = Txt_fechaVie.Text;
        regVieAnterior = Txt_RegistroVie.Text;
        estado.Text = "Ocurrio un postback :S";
    }

    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);//This is important to make the "__doPostBack()" method, works properly

    if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "EliminarProyecto")
    {
        //call the method
        EliminarProyecto();
    }
}

protected void Btn_Actualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Btn_Modificar.Enabled = true;
    Btn_Actualizar.Enabled = false;

    TablaProyectos proyecto = new TablaProyectos();
    string Nombre = nombre;
    Decimal Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(valor);
    //DateTime Fechapropuesta = Convert.ToDateTime(fechapropuesta);
    DateTime Fechavie = Convert.ToDateTime(fechaVie);
    int id_proy = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"]);
    string regVie = renombrarDirectorio();
    proyecto.actualizar(id_proy, Nombre, Valor, Fechavie, regVieAnterior);
    Response.Redirect("~/Modulo_Modificar/ModInfoGeneral.aspx");
}

protected void Mostrar(int id_proy)
{
    int id_proyecto = id_proy;
    TablaProyectos proyectos = new TablaProyectos();
    String[] DatosProyecto = proyectos.DatosProyecto(id_proyecto);

    Session["Id_RegistroVie"] = DatosProyecto[7];
    Session["NombreProyecto"] = DatosProyecto[0];
    Session["ValorProyecto"] = DatosProyecto[1];
    Txt_Nombre.Text = DatosProyecto[0];
    string cad = DatosProyecto[1].Replace(",0000", "");
    Txt_Valor.Text = cad;
    Txt_RegistroVie.Text = DatosProyecto[7];
    DateTime fechaVie = Convert.ToDateTime(DatosProyecto[8]);
    Txt_fechaVie.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", fechaVie);

    //DateTime FechaPropuesta = Convert.ToDateTime(DatosProyecto[3]);
    //Txt_fechaPropuesta.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", FechaPropuesta);
}

protected void Btn_Modificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Txt_Nombre.Enabled = true;
    Txt_Valor.Enabled = true;
    //Txt_fechaPropuesta.Enabled = true;
    Txt_fechaVie.Enabled = true;
    Btn_Actualizar.Enabled = true;
    Btn_Modificar.Enabled = false;
    Txt_RegistroVie.Enabled = true;
}

private string renombrarDirectorio()
{
    string newRegVie = Txt_RegistroVie.Text;
    string root = "~/Pdfs_Subidos/";
    string sourceDirectory = Server.MapPath(root + regVieAnterior);
    string finalDirectory = Server.MapPath(root + newRegVie);
    string finalRegVie;
    string directorioFinal = sourceDirectory;
    var matched = String.Equals(regVieAnterior, newRegVie, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    if (matched)
    {
        // El registro Vie guardado es igual al que se va a guardar
        finalRegVie = regVieAnterior;
    }
    else
    {
        // El registro Vie guardado es diferente al que se va a guardar
        finalRegVie = newRegVie;
        if (Directory.Exists(sourceDirectory))
        {
            try
            {
                //directorioFinal = sourceDirectory + " > "+finalDirectory;
                Directory.Move(sourceDirectory, finalDirectory);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No existe el directorio");
        }
    }

    return finalRegVie;
}

private string hacerPrueba()
{
    string newRegVie = Txt_RegistroVie.Text;
    string root = "~/Pdfs_Subidos/";
    string sourceDirectory = Server.MapPath(root + regVieAnterior);
    string finalDirectory = Server.MapPath(root + newRegVie);
    string finalRegVie;
    string directorioFinal = sourceDirectory;
    var matched = String.Equals(regVieAnterior, newRegVie, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    if (matched)
    {
        // El registro Vie guardado es igual al que se va a guardar
        finalRegVie = regVieAnterior;
        return "hay el mismo regVie capo";
    }
    return regVieAnterior + " & " + newRegVie + " & " + nombre;
}

protected void Btn_Probar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    estado.Text = hacerPrueba();
}

protected void Btn_Terminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["ID"] != null)
        Session.Remove("ID");

    if (Session["Id_RegistroVie"] != null)
        Session.Remove("Id_RegistroVie");

    if (Session["NombreProyecto"] != null)
        Session.Remove("NombreProyecto");

    if (Session["ID_Contrato"] != null)
        Session.Remove("ID_Contrato");

    if (Session["ID_Producto"] != null)
        Session.Remove("ID_Producto");

    if (Session["ID_acta"] != null)
        Session.Remove("ID_acta");

    if (Session["ValorProyecto"] != null)
        Session.Remove("ValorProyecto");

    if (Session["Ultimo"] != null)
        Session.Remove("Ultimo");

    if (Session["ID_adicion"] != null)
        Session.Remove("ID_adicion");

    if (Session["ID_producto"] != null)
        Session.Remove("ID_producto");

    Response.Redirect("~/Modulo_Inicio/Lista.aspx");
}

protected void Btn_Eliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Popup", "deleteAlert();", true);
}

public void EliminarProyecto()
{
    int idproy = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID_Proy"]);
    bool borrado;
    borrado = elm.eliminar(idproy);
    if (borrado)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Popup", "Redireccionar();", true);
    }
}
```

}

El metodo que quiero implementar es el `renombrarDirectorio()` puesto que este me debe devolver el registro Vie que finalmente guardo el usuario.

Comment: Si no he entendido mal, haces el Load y después, cuando modificas el valor, ése se cambia automáticamente y no puedes realizar la comprobación de si se ha modificado el valor. Si es así, has probado de guardar en una variable el valor anterior a la modificación? Ya que en algún lugar tienes que cargar-lo. De todos modos, me parece que falta código para mostrar ya que sólo nos muestras el Load, y tambien nombras un botón Modificar y supongo que un botón para enviar los datos o un evento.

Comment: Ya puse todo el codigo @Marc